# AWK match working locally but not in bash on debian server

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have following strange issue.
I'll try to extract a string from a textfile with awk, but it's not working on the bash at my server.

Textfile looks like (textfile.txt)

```
dummy text name="formtoken" value="bd54839c3348d1c6ed7ab2c266f8a50b" dummy text
```

And I want to fetch the formtoken value out of the file. My awk statement is:

```
awk '/formtoken/ {match($0,/name="formtoken" value="(.{32})"/,arr); print arr[1]}' < textfile.txt
```

Locally the commands result is "bd54839c3348d1c6ed7ab2c266f8a50b"

On the debian server (connected via ssh) I get "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,"

Maybe someone has a good hint for me :)

Thanks,

RCX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian-based distributions use [*Mawk*](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) as the default `awk`, and your command doesn't work with Mawk.

It works with [*Gawk*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) (GNU Awk), which is probably what you've installed locally.

The reason your command doesn't work with Mawk is that you're using the *3*-parameter form of the `match()` function, which is Gawk extension; the function signatures are:

- Gawk: `match(s, r [, a])`
- Mawk (and BSD Awk, and POSIX): `match(s, r)`

---

[Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), in a since cleaned-up comment, suggests using the following variation of the command, which should work with *all* Awks:

```
awk 'sub(/.*name="formtoken" value="/,""){ sub(/".*/,""); print}' textfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for help and the good explanation between the two different awk implementations. @EdMortion your statement works pretty good :)